# and operation in python

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Following is the code that is yielding confusing results.

```
a = None
b = 1
print a and b
if a and b is None:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Here bool(a) is false as it's none. So via short circuit, the expression should return None. This is actually happening. However, during if condition, the condition fails. Although a and b yields None, the condition fails and priting false at the output. Can someone explain why it's happening?

Answer (score 7):

`a and b is None` is evaluated the same as `a and (b is None)`, so the expression evaluates to None, and execution jumps to the else clause.

If you add brackets `(a and b) is None`, then your code will print "True" as you expect.

This is because `is` has a higher precedence than `and` in Python. Take a look at the [operator precedence documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for more details.

Comment: The term for this is operator precedence: `is` has the same precedence as `==` and the other comparators, which makes intuitive  sense.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point - I've added a link to the Python docs.